# Quantlib SOFR swap repricing across 2 different dates

Tags: quantlib, pricing, sofr, ois-swaps

I am trying to price SOFR swaps in two different dates (the same swaps, just different curves and dates)

This are my initial parameters:

```
curve_date =ql.Date (9,5,2022)
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = curve_date

sofr = ql.Sofr() #overnightIndex
swaps_calendar = ql.UnitedStates(ql.UnitedStates.FederalReserve)#calendar
day_count = ql.Actual360() #day count convention
settlement_days = 2 #t+2 settlement convention for SOFR swaps
```

this is the SOFR curve as of May 9th, 2022:

| index | ticker | n | tenor | quote |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | USOSFR1Z CBBT Curncy | 1 | 1 | 0.79 |
| 1 | USOSFR2Z CBBT Curncy | 2 | 1 | 0.81 |
| 2 | USOSFR3Z CBBT Curncy | 3 | 1 | 0.79 |
| 3 | USOSFRA CBBT Curncy | 1 | 2 | 0.8 |
| 4 | USOSFRB CBBT Curncy | 2 | 2 | 1.01 |
| 5 | USOSFRC CBBT Curncy | 3 | 2 | 1.19 |
| 6 | USOSFRD CBBT Curncy | 4 | 2 | 1.34 |
| 7 | USOSFRE CBBT Curncy | 5 | 2 | 1.47 |
| 8 | USOSFRF CBBT Curncy | 6 | 2 | 1.61 |
| 9 | USOSFRG CBBT Curncy | 7 | 2 | 1.71 |
| 10 | USOSFRH CBBT Curncy | 8 | 2 | 1.82 |
| 11 | USOSFRI CBBT Curncy | 9 | 2 | 1.93 |
| 12 | USOSFRJ CBBT Curncy | 10 | 2 | 2.01 |
| 13 | USOSFRK CBBT Curncy | 11 | 2 | 2.09 |
| 14 | USOSFR1 CBBT Curncy | 12 | 2 | 2.17 |
| 15 | USOSFR1F CBBT Curncy | 18 | 2 | 2.48 |
| 16 | USOSFR2 CBBT Curncy | 2 | 3 | 2.62 |
| 17 | USOSFR3 CBBT Curncy | 3 | 3 | 2.69 |
| 18 | USOSFR4 CBBT Curncy | 4 | 3 | 2.72 |
| 19 | USOSFR5 CBBT Curncy | 5 | 3 | 2.73 |
| 20 | USOSFR7 CBBT Curncy | 7 | 3 | 2.77 |
| 21 | USOSFR8 CBBT Curncy | 8 | 3 | 2.78 |
| 22 | USOSFR9 CBBT Curncy | 9 | 3 | 2.8 |
| 23 | USOSFR10 CBBT Curncy | 10 | 3 | 2.81 |
| 24 | USOSFR12 CBBT Curncy | 12 | 3 | 2.83 |
| 25 | USOSFR15 CBBT Curncy | 15 | 3 | 2.85 |
| 26 | USOSFR20 CBBT Curncy | 20 | 3 | 2.81 |
| 27 | USOSFR25 CBBT Curncy | 25 | 3 | 2.71 |
| 28 | USOSFR30 CBBT Curncy | 30 | 3 | 2.6 |
| 29 | USOSFR40 CBBT Curncy | 40 | 3 | 2.4 |
| 30 | USOSFR50 CBBT Curncy | 50 | 3 | 2.23 |

This data is stored in a df called:`swap_data` and I use it to build tuples (rate, (tenor)) for the `OISRateHelper` objects

```
swaps= [(row.quote,(row.n, row.tenor)) for row in swap_data.itertuples(index=True, name='Pandas')]


def zero_curve(settlement_days,swaps,day_count):
    ois_helpers = [ ql.OISRateHelper(settlement_days,                   #settlementDays
                           ql.Period(*tenor),    #tenor -> note that `tenor` in the list comprehension are (n,units), so uses * to unpack when calling ql.Period(n, units)
                           ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(rate/100)),    #fixedRate
                           sofr)                                        #overnightIndex
            for rate, tenor in swaps] 
               
    #for now I have chosen to use a logCubicDiscount term structure to ensure continuity in the inspection
    sofrCurve  = ql.PiecewiseLogCubicDiscount(settlement_days, #referenceDate
                                            swaps_calendar,#calendar
                                            ois_helpers, #instruments 
                                            day_count, #dayCounter
                                         )
               
    sofrCurve.enableExtrapolation() #allows for extrapolation at the ends 
    return sofrCurve
```

using this function I build a zero curve, a sofr object linked to that curve and a swap pricing engine

```
sofrCurve = zero_curve(settlement_days,swaps,day_count)

valuation_Curve = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(sofrCurve)
sofrIndex = ql.Sofr(valuation_Curve)
swapEngine = ql.DiscountingSwapEngine(valuation_Curve)
```

With this I create OIS swaps and price them using this curve to ensure that it's correctly calibrated:

```
effective_date = swaps_calendar.advance(curve_date, settlement_days, ql.Days)
notional = 10_000_000
ois_swaps = []

for rate, tenor in swaps: 
    
    schedule = ql.MakeSchedule(effective_date, 
                               swaps_calendar.advance(effective_date, ql.Period(*tenor)), 
                               ql.Period('1Y'), 
                               calendar = swaps_calendar)
    fixedRate = rate/100
    
    oisSwap = ql.MakeOIS(ql.Period(*tenor), sofrIndex, fixedRate, nominal=notional)
    oisSwap.setPricingEngine(swapEngine)
    ois_swaps.append(oisSwap)
```

the NPVs on all the swaps is zero so they seem. I went a step further to confirm that I was getting the PV of the legs correctly by constructing a function that yields a table with the leg relevant information

```
def leg_information(effective_date, day_count,ois_swap, leg_type, sofrCurve):
    leg_df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['date','yearfrac','CF','discountFactor','PV','totalPV'])
    cumSum_pv= 0
    
    
    leg = ois_swap.leg(0) if leg_type == "fixed" else ois_swap.leg(1) 
    
    for index, cf in enumerate(leg):
        yearfrac = day_count.yearFraction(effective_date,cf.date())
        df = sofrCurve.discount(yearfrac)
        pv = df * cf.amount() 
        cumSum_pv += pv

        row={'date':datetime.datetime(cf.date().year(), cf.date().month(), cf.date().dayOfMonth()),'yearfrac':yearfrac, 'CF':cf.amount() ,'discountFactor':df,'PV':pv,'totalPV':cumSum_pv}
        leg_df.loc[index]=row
        
        
    return leg_df
```

Then I proceeded to view the fixed and float legs for the 30y swap:

```
fixed_leg = leg_information(effective_date, day_count,ois_swaps[-3], 'fixed', sofrCurve)
fixed_leg.tail()
```

| date | yearfrac | CF | discountFactor | PV | totalPV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2048-05-11 | 26.38 | 263343.89 | 0.5 | 132298.29 | 4821684 |
| 2049-05-11 | 27.39 | 264067.36 | 0.49 | 130173.38 | 4951857.39 |
| 2050-05-11 | 28.41 | 264067.36 | 0.48 | 127789.7 | 5079647.08 |
| 2051-05-11 | 29.42 | 264067.36 | 0.48 | 125514.12 | 5205161.2 |
| 2052-05-13 | 30.44 | 266237.78 | 0.47 | 124346.16 | 5329507.36 |

```
float_leg = leg_information(effective_date, day_count,ois_swaps[-3], 'Float', sofrCurve)
float_leg.tail()
```

| date | yearfrac | CF | discountFactor | PV | totalPV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2048-05-11 | 26.38 | 194630.64 | 0.5 | 97778.23 | 4976215.78 |
| 2049-05-11 | 27.39 | 191157.4 | 0.49 | 94232.04 | 5070447.82 |
| 2050-05-11 | 28.41 | 186532.08 | 0.48 | 90268.17 | 5160715.99 |
| 2051-05-11 | 29.42 | 181300.34 | 0.48 | 86174.05 | 5246890.04 |
| 2052-05-13 | 30.44 | 176892.09 | 0.47 | 82617.32 | 5329507.36 |

Also, the DV01 on the swap lines up with what I see in bloomberg:

`ois_swaps[-3].fixedLegBPS()` = $20462.68. So at this point, I feel comfortable with what the swap object because it seems to match what I see on Bloomberg using SWPM

Now, when I change the date:

```
curve_date =ql.Date (9,5,2023)
ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = curve_date
effective_date = swaps_calendar.advance(curve_date, settlement_days, ql.Days)
```

and pull the new curve:

| index | ticker | n | tenor | quote |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | USOSFR1Z CBBT Curncy | 1 | 1 | 5.06 |
| 1 | USOSFR2Z CBBT Curncy | 2 | 1 | 5.06 |
| 2 | USOSFR3Z CBBT Curncy | 3 | 1 | 5.06 |
| 3 | USOSFRA CBBT Curncy | 1 | 2 | 5.07 |
| 4 | USOSFRB CBBT Curncy | 2 | 2 | 5.1 |
| 5 | USOSFRC CBBT Curncy | 3 | 2 | 5.11 |
| 6 | USOSFRD CBBT Curncy | 4 | 2 | 5.11 |
| 7 | USOSFRE CBBT Curncy | 5 | 2 | 5.09 |
| 8 | USOSFRF CBBT Curncy | 6 | 2 | 5.06 |
| 9 | USOSFRG CBBT Curncy | 7 | 2 | 5.03 |
| 10 | USOSFRH CBBT Curncy | 8 | 2 | 4.97 |
| 11 | USOSFRI CBBT Curncy | 9 | 2 | 4.92 |
| 12 | USOSFRJ CBBT Curncy | 10 | 2 | 4.87 |
| 13 | USOSFRK CBBT Curncy | 11 | 2 | 4.81 |
| 14 | USOSFR1 CBBT Curncy | 12 | 2 | 4.74 |
| 15 | USOSFR1F CBBT Curncy | 18 | 2 | 4.28 |
| 16 | USOSFR2 CBBT Curncy | 2 | 3 | 3.96 |
| 17 | USOSFR3 CBBT Curncy | 3 | 3 | 3.58 |
| 18 | USOSFR4 CBBT Curncy | 4 | 3 | 3.39 |
| 19 | USOSFR5 CBBT Curncy | 5 | 3 | 3.3 |
| 20 | USOSFR7 CBBT Curncy | 7 | 3 | 3.24 |
| 21 | USOSFR8 CBBT Curncy | 8 | 3 | 3.23 |
| 22 | USOSFR9 CBBT Curncy | 9 | 3 | 3.24 |
| 23 | USOSFR10 CBBT Curncy | 10 | 3 | 3.24 |
| 24 | USOSFR12 CBBT Curncy | 12 | 3 | 3.27 |
| 25 | USOSFR15 CBBT Curncy | 15 | 3 | 3.3 |
| 26 | USOSFR20 CBBT Curncy | 20 | 3 | 3.28 |
| 27 | USOSFR25 CBBT Curncy | 25 | 3 | 3.2 |
| 28 | USOSFR30 CBBT Curncy | 30 | 3 | 3.12 |
| 29 | USOSFR40 CBBT Curncy | 40 | 3 | 2.93 |
| 30 | USOSFR50 CBBT Curncy | 50 | 3 | 2.73 |

store the above data in `swap_data` and proceed again to recalibrate the zero curve:

```
swaps= [(row.quote,(row.n, row.tenor)) for row in swap_data.itertuples(index=True, name='Pandas')]
sofrCurve_2023 = zero_curve(settlement_days,swaps,day_count)
valuation_Curve2023 = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(sofrCurve_2023)
sofrIndex2023 = ql.Sofr(valuation_Curve2023)
swapEngine2023 = ql.DiscountingSwapEngine(valuation_Curve2023)
ois_swaps[-3].setPricingEngine(swapEngine2023)
```

and try to get the NPV of the swap

```
ois_swaps[-3].NPV()
```

It yields a value of $60968.42 .

I know that the NPV after changing the date forward is wrong. I did I simple calculation: the 30y swap rate moved from 2.60 to 3.12 ( I know it's a 29y swap 1 year later, but for illustration purposes the P&L is more less -20k* 52bps = -$1,040,000.

and If I try to view the floating leg by calling:

```
float_leg = leg_information(effective_date, day_count,ois_swaps[-3], 'Float', sofrCurve)
float_leg.tail()
```

I get the following:

```
RuntimeError: Missing SOFRON Actual/360 fixing for May 11th, 2022
```

Which makes me think that I need to relink to the OvernightIndex to `sofrIndex2023` on that 30y swap (I just don't know how to do this, I have looked at the documentation and there's no hints about how to do this)

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I realise the question is specifically about Quantlib, but I wanted to highlight an answer using Rateslib for Python, the answer is around 1.05mm USD as you predicted.

Setup your initial curve (note I have ignored most swaps to just approximate the 30y test swap)

```python
from rateslib import Curve, IRS, dt, Solver
curve = Curve(
    nodes={
        dt(2022, 5, 9): 1.0,
        dt(2047, 5, 9): 1.0,
        dt(2052, 5, 9): 1.0,
    },
    id="sofr"
)
sofr_kws = dict(
    payment_lag=2,
    frequency="A",
    convention="act360",
    effective=dt(2022, 5, 11),
    calendar="nyc",
    curves="sofr",
)
instruments = [
    IRS(termination="25y", **sofr_kws),
    IRS(termination="30y", **sofr_kws),
]
solver = Solver(
    curves=[curve], 
    instruments=instruments,
    s=[2.71, 2.60],
    instrument_labels=["25Y", "30Y"],
    id="SOFR"
)
```

Then we created your tess IRS and check its NPV.

```python
>>> test_irs = IRS(termination="30Y", **sofr_kws, fixed_rate=2.60, notional=10e6)
>>> test_irs.npv(solver=solver)
<Dual: 0.000932, ('sofr0', 'sofr1', 'sofr2'), [  7464130.57816169  -4800825.36772211 -10833705.54868424]>
```

Then we build a second curve with new dates and rates.

```python
curve2 = Curve(
    nodes={
        dt(2023, 5, 9): 1.0,
        dt(2048, 5, 9): 1.0,
        dt(2053, 5, 9): 1.0,
    },
    id="sofr"
)
sofr_kws2 = dict(
    payment_lag=2,
    frequency="A",
    convention="act360",
    effective=dt(2023, 5, 11),
    calendar="nyc",
    curves="sofr",
)
instruments = [
    IRS(termination="25y", **sofr_kws2),
    IRS(termination="30y", **sofr_kws2),
]
solver2 = Solver(
    curves=[curve2], 
    instruments=instruments,
    s=[3.2, 3.12],
    instrument_labels=["25Y", "30Y"],
    id="SOFR"
)
```

We need to add the fixings for the test IRS since it has a payment settlement coming up. I took a look at historical fixings and the average over last year has been about 3%.

```python
test_irs = IRS(termination="30Y", **sofr_kws, fixed_rate=2.60, notional=10e6, leg2_fixings=3.0)
test_irs.npv(solver=solver2)
<Dual: 1,049,569.356238, ('sofr0', 'sofr1', 'sofr2'), [ 7596484.75971786 -6798185.22482419 -8777872.59764332]>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup your objects so that you can change the curve they're using.  In QuantLib, that's done via relinkable handles.  Before you create the swaps, when you do:

```
sofrCurve = zero_curve(settlement_days,swaps,day_count)

valuation_Curve = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(sofrCurve)
sofrIndex = ql.Sofr(valuation_Curve)
swapEngine = ql.DiscountingSwapEngine(valuation_Curve)
```

replace the second line with:

```
valuation_Curve = ql.RelinkableYieldTermStructureHandle(sofrCurve)
```

which gives you the possibility to change the curve inside the handle.

Later, when you change the evaluation date, instead of:

```
sofrCurve_2023 = zero_curve(settlement_days,swaps,day_count)
valuation_Curve2023 = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(sofrCurve_2023)
sofrIndex2023 = ql.Sofr(valuation_Curve2023)
swapEngine2023 = ql.DiscountingSwapEngine(valuation_Curve2023)
ois_swaps[-3].setPricingEngine(swapEngine2023)
```

you'll do:

```
sofrCurve_2023 = zero_curve(settlement_days,swaps,day_count)
valuation_Curve.linkTo(sofrCurve_2023)
```

Instead of rebuilding the Sofr index and the engine, the above lets the old objects use the new curve.

Comment: Would it have been a better design to keep just the instrument in one object - containing e.g. the name of the index used to reset the floater coupons, not needing to be relinked or otherwise modified - and the market data for the given date, including historical index values and projection curves, in a separate pricing environment object?

Comment: "better" depends on the use cases, but yes, it's certainly viable.  You would probably still relink projection curves in the pricing environment.

Comment: Sensitivities calculation would be one example of a common use case: given many "bumps" (risk scenarios, e.g. bump some tenor of the projection curve), for each scenario, create a bumped pricing environment derived from the base pricing environment, reprice the same instrument object in a scenario-specific thread. There's no need to copy the instrument.